NestedScrollView with a ListView in body, constraint problem
The problem is with the body of the NestedScrollView, the ListView.builder which returns ProductInfoTile widgets is wrapped in a SizedBox. This SizedBox is too big for the screen when the NestedScrollView is not scrolled.
See this screenshot, this is when the screen is initially loaded:
screen initial load
And this is it with it scrolled down:
screen after scrolling
The ideal behavior would be for the NestedScrollView to scroll first, then the ListView take over in scrolling the menu items. This is currently working, but the constraints are wrong. I am getting overflow errors.
Can anyone help? Thank you

class ViewState extends State<_InventoryView> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            Color appBarBackGroundColor = Colors.white;
            const borderRadius = BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              topRight: Radius.circular(30),
            );
            return [
              ...
            ];
          },
          // Product Details
          body: Container(
            color: ColorRes.lightGreyBackground,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: ColorRes.lightGreyBackground,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        truncateName(
                                            widget.storeInfo.name ?? '', 20),
                                        style: AppTextStyles.style18BoldBlack,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(width: 5),
                                      GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            ...
                                          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle,
                                              color: ColorRes.primaryColor))
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              if (widget.storeInfo.weightedRatingValue != null)
                                Container(
                                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                                  ),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                    child: RatingBarWidget(
                                      onRatingChanged: null,
                                      rating: widget.storeInfo.weightedRatingValue!,
                                      size: 15,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 15),
                          PreferredSize(
                            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(82.5),
                            child: SelectedOrderServiceTypeInfoView(
                                showDistance: true,
                                distance: widget.storeInfo.miles ?? 0.0),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Store Menu
                  (inventoryCtrlObj.isInventoryLoading)
                      ? const LoadingWidget()
                      : (inventoryCtrlObj.getInventoryData == null)
                      ? const SizedBox()
                      : StatefulBuilder(
                    builder: (context, setStoreProductPageState) {
                      return Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Consumer<ProductController>(
                                builder: (context, productCtrlObj, _) {
                                  return SizedBox(
                                    height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                        .size
                                        .height *
                                        0.8,
                                    child: ListView.builder(
                                      physics:
                                      const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                      itemCount: productCtrlObj
                                          .storeItemsList.length,
                                      itemBuilder:
                                          (context, storeProductIndex) {
                                        final product =
                                        productCtrlObj.storeItemsList[
                                        storeProductIndex];
                                        return ProductInfoTile(
                                          product,
                                          isStoreProducts: true,
                                          isInRow: true,
                                          press: () {
                                            navigateToProductDetailPage(
                                                context, product);
                                          },
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}


